# Excel - highlight date range within another date range

Tags: excel, date

Working on a booking system on Excel, I have two components to make it works:

Tab1 - The booking system itself showing from which date range any element is booked
(eg, Element A booked from the 21/10/2014 to the 28/10/2014),

Tab2 - A calendar highlighting availability for each booking

Currently, the calendar stresses whether an element is available or not and highlight conflict (booking at the same date) for a given element.

What I would like to add is a sort of error message (or color conditional formatting) within the booking system (Tab 2) if two elements are overlapping.
Eg. element A booked from the 21/10/2014 to the 28/10/2014 and element B booked from the 26/10/2014 to the 30/10/2014.

Problem is that I have not been able to add this type of conditional formatting since it depends on a date range.

[image]
Link to the file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ehwckfr9d3iknca/Booking%20system.xls?dl=0

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Geralt

Comment: show us your sheets.

Comment: Sure, I have edited the question with the Spreadsheet.

Comment: You should also embed screenshots in your question... Not all of us have access to dropbox while we are at work.

Comment: I have added a screenshot to the question.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Select Booking sheet > select C or D column cell to apply formatting > `Conditional Formatting > New Rule`.

Add two Rules for two columns. `Use a formula to determine which cells to format` should be selected.

Formula for two columns are :

`=C4<=OFFSET(C4;-1;1)`  and  `=D3>=OFFSET(D3;1;-1)`

*Special attention* :

*a. C4 and D3 as starting of formatting 
b. Ranges onto which these are applied.*

See the image below to get the idea:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working on my spreadsheet.
Not sure what I am missing since I have reproduced what you have written above..

Comment: you have to adjust it to your sheet. see special attention section in the answer. And post what part is not working.

Comment: I am not sure tbh. Here is what I have at the moment:
http://imgur.com/HBVyClX
Note that for some reason, the two last rules are different from yours (the "applies to" part). Have you changed them?

Comment: I think I have found whats going wrong. Your file extension is xls and somehow I made that xlsx. What version of excel are you using?

Comment: I am using Excel 2007. Could that be the problem?

Comment: save as .xlsx, then try. It should work then. IF work mark as answer, otherwise comment.

Comment: This is still not working, both .xls and .xlsx
What about the two last formulas in your conditional formatting screenshot? I have different one in mine if you check.
Thanks

Comment: last two formula changed somehow. After making them like yours, worked fine. I believe you cant use conditional formatting in xls file. I got a compatibility popup while saving. Then saveas .xlsx and formatting worked fine.

Comment: Still can't get this running properly for some reason :(
Any other idea?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h88m5yubqhboxfh/Booking%20system.xlsx?dl=0 is the file I tried.

Comment: Awesome, it works well on yours! Still can't get why though ...
Last question; is there a simple way to make the formatting dependent of the ID field as well?
That way, availability and double booking would be highlighted only for elements of the same ID.

Comment: you want to highlight rows in booking sheet where ID's same, right?

Comment: Yes - adding a condition to overlapping time frame + depending on ID.
Eg. On the screenshot above, only rows 3 and 5 should get highlighted because booking time frame overlap from one to another and they have the same ID.

Comment: you can select the ID column > conditional formatting > highlight cells rules > duplicate. By the way, FYI: you should post on stackoverflow for coding related issue, otherwise post on superuser.com

Comment: Aaah right, sorry, I will post on the proper site next time! Besides this, I am not sure it would work with what you've just written.
The row needs to be formatted if these two conditions match: if both the dates are overlapping and if the ID is the same.
Do you see what I mean?

Comment: if overlapping dates are next to each other, I can think of that right now. But if overlapping occurs for more than 1 row gap, then coding would be the way to go for formatting after all.

Comment: By coding you mean Macro and all?